# Consulta SQL agrupar resultados

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, firebird

Tengo que realizar una consulta para poder realizar un procedimiento que arroje los siguientes resultados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El detalle es que yo tengo dos campos, uno que guarda el monto llamado MONTO_ME y otro llamado MONEDA donde almacena el código, en total tengo esta tres monedas y quisiera mostrarlo de acuerdo a la imagen anterior, la consulta SQL donde observo la información es la siguiente:

```
  SELECT
   cd.correlativo_principal,
   c.documento,
   cd.monto_me,
   cd.moneda_codigo
FROM
   caja_detalles cd
   join caja c on (c.correlativo = cd.correlativo_principal)
```

Sin embargo, esta consulta me trae lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy utilizando el manejador de base de datos IBExpert para bases de datos **Firebird**, intenté agrupar por CASE pero no resultó, intenté hacer una subconsulta con un where indicando el código de moneda (los cuáles ya conozco), que son 02, 03 y 04.

Si me pudieran orientar les sabría agradecer.

Comment: Eso se llama tabla pivotante.. no hay nada de eso en firebird?

Comment: estuve buscando, eso, y también tablas agregadas, pero creo que eso no es lo que necesito hacer, ¿no es posible realizarlo sin necesidad de crear una tabla adicional sino identificando de acuerdo a la moneda que tenga y colocar el monto directamente allí? gracias por su respuesta

Comment: eso que mostras, de transformar filas en columnas, se llama tabla pivotante. No conozco firebird, pero muchas bd tienen funciones para eso...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer 3 subconsultas una para cada codigo de la moneda

```
 SELECT
   cd.correlativo_principal,
   c.documento,
   (
select count(*) from caja_detalles cd2 where cd2.correlativo_principal=c.correlativo
and moneda_codigo like '02'
) as MONEDA_02,
   (
select count(*) from caja_detalles cd2 where cd2.correlativo_principal=c.correlativo
and moneda_codigo= '03'
)as MONEDA_03,
(
select count(*) from caja_detalles cd2 where cd2.correlativo_principal=c.correlativo
and moneda_codigo= '04'
)as MONEDA_04,
FROM
   caja_detalles cd
   join caja c on (c.correlativo = cd.correlativo_principal)
group by cd.correlativo_principal,
   c.documento
```

Si tienes un script para crear la tabla y datos de prueba puedo ayudarte mejor con la consulta espero funcione.

Comment: Ojala no sean 15 los codigos :)...

Comment: Me funciono, no lo use con el count como tu, pero hice un SUM(MONTO_ME) y me arrojó el resultado que esperaba, muchas gracias

Comment: @AmbarVegas y xq no me marcas como respuesta correcta :(

Comment: Perdón se me paso, ya está